# How to build a .jar out of scala in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark, jar

I am trying to run a scala code using spark-submit. I have to convert the scala code into a .jar and then execute. I tried to convert .scala file to .jar directly but I got `"NoClassFoundException"`.

Then I tried to call scala class from java file and convert java file to a .jar and execute using spark-submit. But this time java class is found but scala class is not found. When I run this in my eclipse it is giving expected output

**java class**

```
package com.connect.cassandra;

public class MainClass {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              MainScalaClass app = new MainScalaClass();
              app.main(args);
       }

}
```

**Scala class**

```
package com.connect.cassandra

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

class MainScalaClass {
       def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         simpleCassConnector.foo()
       }
}

object simpleCassConnector {
def foo(){
  println("inside object")
       val cluster = Cluster.builder()
         .addContactPoint("localhost")
         .withPort(9042)
         .build()

         val session = cluster.connect()
         val p = session.execute("Select * from persons.user limit 2")
         println(p.all())   
}
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/connect/cassandra/MainScalaClass
```

where am I going wrong and is there any way to directly convert scala file to .jar and execute without `"NoClassFound"` exception?

Comment: are u using Maven?...If not create a Maven Project to avoid this issue..while creating Jar

Comment: Can you tell us , how you build jar from eclipse ?

Comment: I am using maven. I built it  by doing right click on the file and export it to a local folder byr giving it a name

Comment: Also if I do maven build on the project, it's build is failure

Comment: That means there are compile time issues in the project. (Check if the scala class is in build path)

Comment: RIght click on project -> properties -> java build path -> Add folder -> check scala folder -> save/apply